# Translation of "Please call me Bill"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate

> Please call me Bill.

Would it be

> Bitte nennen Sie mich Bill.

or

> Bitte heißen Sie mich Bill.

or some other verbs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be:

> Bitte nennen Sie mich Bill.

as `heißen` is not used in this context. If you want to use something more informal you coud use:

> Bitte nenne mich Bill

or even more informal (e.g. to a friend)

> Nenn mich einfach Bill `(Just call me Bill)`

Answer (score 7):

"heißen" today is used only in the following verb construction: "heißen" + name: Wie heißt du?

> Ich heiße Hans.
>
> "Er hieß ihn einen Lügner",

something like that you will only find in older literature.

In the above situation I would say, if you use "du":

> Bitte, nenn mich Bill. / Bitte, sag doch einfach Bill (zu mir).
>   Du kannst mich Bill nennen.
>   Bill reicht.

Wenn you say "Sie":

> Ach bitte, nennen Sie mich doch einfach Bill.
>   Sie können Bill zu mir sagen.